# Merge Linked List - Not working python

Tags: python, linked-list

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the below code:

```
class Node(object):

   def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
       self.data = data
       self.next = next_node

class Solution:
    def MergeLists(self,headA, headB):

        current = Node()
        temp = current
        while not (headA is None and headB is None ):
                if(headA.data <= headB.data) :
                    temp.next = headA
                    headA = headA.next
                else:
                    temp.next = headB
                    headB = headB.next
                temp = temp.next
        if headA is None:
            temp.next = headB
        if headB is None:
            temp.next = headA

        return current.next
```

Please let me know what I did wrong here. I am learning python

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what is your problem? [ask]

Comment: I do not code in Python, but I applied your code to even a simple case of two lists each having only node and it failed completely.

Comment: The code fails to merge the two list. It shows compile time error. But I dont get it why it shows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the temp variable is modified each time in the loop, instead you could try

```
       if(headA.data<=headB.data):
           temp = headA
           headA = headA->next
       else:
           temp = headB
           headB = headB->next
       while not (headA is None and headB is None ):
            if(headA.data <= headB.data) :
                temp->next = headA
                headA = headA.next
            else:
                temp->next = headB
                headB = headB.next
```

Comment: Yeah. I understand it but I am still getting compile time error. Don't understand what is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: MergeLists([1,2,3], [4,6,7,0]) I tried to trigger like this to check but it fails saying :class Node(object),     A = MergeLists([1,2,3], [4,6,7,0])
TypeError: MergeLists() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: It looks like you are using an online code judge (e.g. leetcode?). Try `self.MergeLists(a, b)` if trying to call `MergeLists()` from within an instance of `Solution`. If calling externally, you need an instance of the `Solution` class, e.g. `s = Solution()`. Then call `s.MergeLists(a, b)`.  Also it looks like you are trying to pass Python lists to `MergeLists()`, but `MergeLists()` expects two `Node` objects.